# How to set properties of background image in reactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web

I was able to get the background of my header container to show an image. However, i dont k ow how to set the size of the BACKGROUND IMAGE. SO what appears in the heading container just shows a image that is too big to appear in the header container.

I tried to search online
Change the sizes of the containers using vh and vw
Using Inline styles

```
//App.js
import React from "react";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";

const ContactUs = () => {
    return(
        <div className="contactUsContainer">
            <NavBar/>
            <div className="contactUsHeader">
                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ContactUs;


//app.css

.contactUsContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

.contactUsHeader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("http://www.stapl.co.in/sites/default/files/imagecache/full-zoom/files/projects/6/83/6-83-wartsilla-3.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height:30vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: blue

}
```

Expected Result: background image to show full image, just in smaller size

Actual Result: background image shows very big, which omits much of the image content

[image]

[image: e]

Comment: This has nothing to do with React. What you seem to need is simply `background-size: contain;`

Comment: Right, you rather need the exact ratio for the height: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/9j0ectb3/

Comment: hey thanks for your response. I tried all possible [roperties for background-size. Please see image above for what i get when i set background-size: contain.

Comment: im trying to get the image to be like how this page got it setup. So as to not cover the page
https://www.yamibuy.com/article/473953

Comment: Well, for one that [yamibuy image](https://cdn.yamibuy.net/sns/ea717f6a04b5c85ffd2f98f8c143d3c0_0x0.png) is much much wider than tall. I'm not clear what you're asking? Surely you don't want to squash the image into a very wide area? In case you're looking to center it, I've updated the fiddle.

Comment: True! Why I didnt think of that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do without any dirty JS is:

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
```

Then you just need to pick the right ratio for your image